# Find similarity between two datasets

Tags: time-series, similarities

In data science or statistics, what techniques are there to find the similarity between two datasets?

I.e. let's say I have 2 sets of data, a) max temperatures for the month of February and b) max temps for March. Both lines will be an erratic line on a X Y chart or in a 2 dimensional plane. What technique would one use to calculate the similarities between these two lines on chart?

Edit, what I mean with similarity is both the shape of the line i.e. in my example two lines will be similar if they both have say hotter weeks in the first week and then 3 colder weeks but also, if their values are similar for the days in the month

Edit edit, my example is just an example, I'm not actually comparing temps in months but I use this example as it explains my actual problem so months being of unequal days etc does not matter here.

Comment: Because the number of days in Feb differs from the number of days in Mar, a scatterplot of the two months will require some adjustment and explanation. It would make more sense to me if you wanted to compare Feb weather in two consecutive years. // It does make sense to see if mean or median temperatures for the two months differ.  My answer focuses on whether March is significantly warmer than Feb.--both for normal and for non-normal data.

Comment: You need a Vector Autoregressive (VAR) model. The cross-autoregression coefficients would tell you what you want to know.

Comment: updated question, my actual problem I'm trying to solve is not temp's over months but I used this as it accurately describes my real data sets. My real data sets would be of similar size

Comment: I believe that this 'update' fundamentally changes your question, perhaps making it unanswerable for data from a February and March of a given year. In any case, my Answer seems no longer relevant, so I am deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

The word "similarities" is not clear defined.

For your example, you can run T-test to see if two data have same mean value. We can run an statistical test to see if the average temperatures for two months are the same.

In addition, we can fit two models to the two data sets, and compare to models. Assume you want to fit the Gaussian distribution to the temperature for each month, you can compare the mean and standard deviation of the two models.

Comment: edited original question

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple correlation coefficient work? For example:

```
x <- sin(seq(0, 10, by= 0.1))

march <- x + rnorm(length(x), sd= 0.2)
feb <- x + rnorm(length(x), sd= 0.2)

plot(1:length(x), march, xlab= 'Day', ylab= 'Temp')
points(1:length(x), feb, col= 'blue')

r <- cor(feb, march)
legend('bottomright', legend= sprintf('corr = %.2f', r))
```

[image]

But I don't think there is a unique, general answer to your question and in fact there are various metrics for similarity and distance.

Comment: in what can I run your script sample to play with it?

Comment: It's R - you can run it on an interactive session.